# Selenium and WhitePages

Tags: css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to signup on https://secure.whitepages.com/signup. They requested to enter my first name, last name, email and password.

For name I tried locating element by CSS using the following syntax but I got element not found exception:

```
"input#name_fname"
```

But all I got was error.

What is correct syntax for name, email and password?

Comment: You can use xpath instead of css selector.

Comment: I tried XPath and got a different error so I went back to CSS bec they say it is faster

Answer (score 0):

Use These xpath's for name,email and password:
Xpath of name:

```
//input[@id='user_fname']
     or
//input[@title='Enter your first name']
```

xpath of Email:

```
//input[@id='user_email']
```

xpath of password:

```
//input[@id='user_password']
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me check if it works. What about CSS - what would I use?

Comment: Oh, and this        //input[@id='user_fname] did not work.. I just tried it. And I tried it before but I'm getting XPath not present..

Comment: use title instead of id.

Comment: If that doesn't work then give implicit wait for driver.

Comment: It didn't work either.. Do have any idea why not? I already have 10 second implicit wait., is it working on your machine?

Comment: I added implicit wait in "Main" and passed driver to class as parameter do I need to add implicit wait in each class or only once in original driver?

Comment: You can add implicit wait only once to the driver which should be same as your passing to classes. But why are passing to different classes, you can find element there only na. Once find Element in main method itself.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried using Xpath and worked for me. Please try this.

**Its always better to declare some wait time with driver. Better to declare it with driver initialization/profiling. 
Here may be your code was not working due to wait issues.** I have tried using Xpath and worked for me. Please try this.

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;


public class Whitepages
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Whitepages.loadPage("https://secure.whitepages.com/signup");
}
public static void loadPage(String url)
{
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get(url);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
       System.out.println("Browser opned");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='user_fname']")).sendKeys("Fname");
       System.out.println("Entered Fname");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='user_lname']")).sendKeys("Lname");
       System.out.println("Entered Lname");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='user_email']")).sendKeys("flag1234@gmail.com");
       System.out.println("Entered email");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='user_password']")).sendKeys("water123");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='centered top-padding clear-all']/input")).click();
    System.out.println("Welcome to whitePages");
    driver.quit();      
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try **driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#user_fname"));**. If you want to test through firefox/ie console, try following command in the same -> **document.querySelector("#user_fname")**. This css locator is only for First Name.